# Fourier Transform and $f*g$ convolution

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

Given the 3 following:
$$\mathfrak{F}(e^{-|t|})=\sqrt\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+\omega^2}$$
$$\mathfrak{F}(r(t))=\sqrt\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\sin \omega}{\omega}$$
where
$$r(t)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1, &\left | t \right |<1\\ 
0, &\left | t \right |>1
\end{matrix}\right.$$
I can say that if $f(t)={\mathfrak{F}}^{-1}\left ( \frac{\sin \omega}{\omega(1+\omega^2)} \right )$ then
$$f(t)=\sqrt\frac{\pi}{2}r(t)*\sqrt\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-|t|}$$ or
$$f(t)=\frac{\pi}{2}r(t)*e^{-|t|}$$
Now I want to find $f(0)$ and $f(1)$.
How could this be done?

And, what is the relation between $f(\omega)$ and $\mathfrak{F}\left(\frac{\sin t}{t(1+t^2)} \right)$ [if there is any].

Answer (score 0):

You should write it as $f(t) = \frac\pi2 (r \ast e^{-|\cdot|})(t)$ to not reuse $t$. These two things are just two definite convolution integrals:

$$f(0) = \int_{-1}^1 e^{-|t|} \mathrm dt\\
f(1) = \int_{-1}^1 e^{-|t-1|} \mathrm dt$$

Regarding the last question, know that $\mathfrak F(\mathfrak F(f))(t) = f(-t)$ for any $f\in L^1(\mathbb R) \cap L^2(\mathbb R)$

Comment: I don't understand your 1st sentence: "... to not reuse $t$." Could you rephrase it?

Comment: Well, $f(t) = r(t) \ast \exp(-|t|)$ implies that $f(t) = \text{constant} \ast \text{constant}$... It's just false in any way. Convolution is a binary operator _on functions_ while $r(t)$ is a _number_ in this context.